# Rails 3.2, Heroku - can't display my page - error 500

Tags: deployment, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Whole day I am struggling with the deployment of my app to Heroku. Still getting there the error 500, specifically this is the output from log:

```
2012-03-09T16:56:25+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEPRECATION] Paperclip::Attachment.interpolations is deprecated and will be removed from future versions. Use Paperclip.interpolates instead
2012-03-09T16:56:28+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
2012-03-09T16:56:28+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-03-09T16:56:28+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:21464, CTRL+C to stop
2012-03-09T16:56:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-03-09T16:56:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-09T16:56:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-09T16:56:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for _my_ip_ at 2012-03-09 16:56:31 +0000
2012-03-09T16:56:32+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-03-09T16:56:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET url_app.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=870ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-03-09T16:56:33+00:00 heroku[router]: GET url_app.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-03-09T16:56:33+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
```

What is there wrong? The log says nothing exactly, I am not sure where to search the problem... Locally works me the app well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you clarify if:

1. What are the steps leading up to these logs: Did you try to access it in the browser or using "heroku open" from the CLI?
2. Was the app running successfully before and has now stopped working or is the first time you are deploying to heroku?
3. Is the "url_app" in your logs an edit made by you or in the logs verbatim?

Here are a couple of suggestions you could try:

1. If the "url_app" is verbatim from the logs, there seems to be a redirect issue with the app configuration. Try running "heroku open" from the CLI to get to the right URL
2. Run "heroku status" on the CLI to check if it's a heroku problem

If you could provide the above details, I'd be able to help better.